# time offset of influxdb continuous query not working

Tags: time, offset, influxdb

I'm trying influxdb continuous query with time offset. However the query didn't work.

Here is my CQ:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY perf_cq_1m ON temp 
BEGIN
     SELECT mean(rate) AS rate INTO temp.autogen.perf_cq_1m FROM 
     temp.autogen.perflog GROUP BY time(1m, 2h) fill(0) 
END
```

I'd like the query to shift forward 2h to test the functionality. But the clause `GROUP BY time(1m, 2h)` didn't do what it is demonstrated in the [influxDB documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/continuous_queries/#basic-syntax).

Influx log shows that the continuous query execute with UTC time boundaries, regradless of the `GROUP BY time[1m, 2h]` clause. Log is as follows:

```
2019-03-29T02:40:00.510257Z info Continuous query execution (start) {"log_id": "0ETp9740000", "service": "continuous_querier", "trace_id": "0ETpwX~W000", "op_name": "continuous_querier_execute", "op_event": "start"}
2019-03-29T02:40:00.511279Z info Executing continuous query {"log_id": "0ETp9740000", "service": "continuous_querier", "trace_id": "0ETpwX~W000", "op_name": "continuous_querier_execute", "name": "perf_cq_1m", "db_instance": "temp", "start": "2019-03-29T02:39:00.000000Z", "end": "2019-03-29T02:40:00.000000Z"}
2019-03-29T02:40:00.512286Z info Executing query {"log_id": "0ETp9740000", "service": "query", "query": "SELECT mean(rate) AS rate INTO temp.autogen.perf_cq_1m FROM temp.autogen.perflog WHERE time >= '2019-03-29T02:39:00Z' AND time < '2019-03-29T02:40:00Z' GROUP BY time(1m, 2h) fill(0)"}
```

The localtime is `2019-03-29 10:40:00`.

As far as i am concerned, the clause `GROUP BY time(<interval>,<offset>)` make  CQ executes at localtime with time range in UTC time in the `where time > '' and time < ''` clause, rather than altering both execute time and time boundaries.

So did I miss anything?
Any help is appreciated.